# Relying on the iteration order of an unmodified HashSet

Tags: c#, mono, ienumerable, hashset

```
HashSet<object> myHashSet = new HashSet<object>();

// Iteration 1
foreach (object myObject in myHashSet) { ... }

// Some instructions THAT DO NOT MODIFY myHashSet
...

// Iteration 2
foreach (object myObject in myHashSet) { ... }
```

Will the objects of `myHashSet` be enumerated in the same order in both iterations?

Comment: While there is no technical reason why order would change, since it would require special code that varies order based on something outside f source collection... But relying on it is not a good idea since the only official documentation about order in [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is "If order or element duplication is more important than performance for your application, consider using the `List<T>` class together with the `Sort` method.".

Comment: You can also check reference source http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,2d265edc718b158b to see how it is implemented (again - relying on implementation details is generally not good idea).

Comment: Maybe you can use a SortedSet object instead of a HashSet.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Since the question is tagged "mono", the Microsoft reference source may not be relevant. Although, obviously, the Mono team would be crazy to deviate, and any reasonable standalone implementation would still be deterministic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the reference source of `HashSet` ([link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,61c6bd9b8ecf54e9)), the iteration order is predictable in the absence of set modifications.

```
public bool MoveNext() {
    if (version != set.m_version) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion));
    }

    while (index < set.m_lastIndex) {
        if (set.m_slots[index].hashCode >= 0) {
            current = set.m_slots[index].value;
            index++;
            return true;
        }
        index++;
    }
    index = set.m_lastIndex + 1;
    current = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

However unlikely, this could change in future versions of the .NET platforms, or in other implementations. To ensure that the order stays the same, make a list from the set on the first iteration, and use the list for your second iteration:

```
var myList = myHashSet.ToList();
foreach( var obj myObject in myList) ...
// Some instructions (may or may not modify myHashSet, it no longer matters)
foreach( var obj myObject in myList) ...
```

Comment: I was dealing with Mono. However if you have a look at https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Collections.Generic/HashSet.cs#L626 it also seems to iterate through the set with a predictable order.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible answers to this, really.

The first is "yes, because enumerating a `HashSet` is deterministic, and you can simply look in the source if you don't believe me".

The second is "no, because if you want to get technical, the documentation for `HashSet<T>.GetEnumerator()` does not say the order is deterministic, so tomorrow the implementation could change".

You would not be wrong going with the first answer to get work done. If you want to be absolutely, positively sure, you can of course use `myHashSet.ToArray()` and iterate only over that, but introducing a copy just for a technicality may very well be overkill. In this case, an implementation would have to go *out of its way* to implement an enumeration that is *not* deterministic.

One important caveat, though: you are not wrong to stress that the `HashSet` isn't modified in between enumerations, because it *is* reasonable for an implementation to change the order when the set changes (which would depend on how items are stored internally).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. dasblinkenlight's answer was roughly the same but I appreciated the snippets.